# Dynamically import HTML template in Dart Polymer

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I've succedded in dynamically create a polymer component with dart and add to the dom.

But now I would like to do this *WITHOUT* having to statically import the HTML template at compile time.

In my use case I have a div container with id `myContainer` and a custom Polymer Dart component whose tag is `my-tag`.

I've tryied with:

```
LinkElement e = new LinkElement('link');
e.rel = 'import';
e.href= 'my-tag.html';
document.head.children.add(e);

$['myContainer'].children.add(new Element.tag('my-tag'));
```

But this ends up with the following exception :

```
Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Nodes of type 'HTML' may not be inserted inside nodes of type '#document'. 
...
```

Note that the exception is raisen when the polymer element is added to the dom and not when adding the link tag. Also the same code works if adding the link at compile time and commenting the code that adds it at runtime.

I've tried also with several different variants of the code above, mainly adding the link tag in a separate method called before `polymerInit` or inside `polymerInit().run(...)` but nothing changes.

I'm wondering if this use case is even supported.

Comment: Why do you not want to add the imports statically?  I think Polymer transformers needs them when you build the project.

Comment: Because I'd like to create a library of components that gets shown in a content area by a navigation framework as the user clicks around. I already need to import every component from dart side of the "navigator" but this is not so bad as I need to register the "routes". But I'm trying to find a way not to include the HTML templates too on the HTML side and minimize the work that need to be done to add a new "page".

Comment: You can create a transformer.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer sounds interesting. Can you expand this concept ?

Comment: I don't have experience with building transformers yet. A transformer is executed by `pub build` and `pub serve` and can analyze and modify the code during the build process. https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html, https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers/

Answer (score 1):

It might be possible to create a transformer that does that.
A transformer is executed by pub build and pub serve and can analyze and modify the code during the build process. dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html, dartlang.org/tools/pub/transformers

or

(I haven't tried it but I assume it will work)
You can create an HTML file containing all imports your package needs and the user of your package only needs to import this one file.

Comment: Creating a single html file that imports all the others doesn't work. But the transformer way sounds interesting, I'll investigate.

Comment: I think this is what Dart core-elements and paper-elements do see for example https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/blob/master/lib/core_animated_pages.html

Comment: mmh. not sure the import for core_selector in that case is wanted (it is repeated in the private implementation), the other import is used in  that template (infact it is the template), this is not like exporting for use in another file.

Comment: But when you use this element in a Polymer.dart app you just import this file.

Comment: I'll try again because this was a solution I checked some times ago but it didn't work. I'll double check it.

Comment: ok, of course, having a html file that importa all the other works. probably I skrewed up something. I'll go with that solution for a while but I'll investigate more deeply the `transformer` option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an HeadElement:

```
 LinkElement e = new LinkElement();
 e.rel = 'import';
 e.href= 'my-tag.html';
 HeadElement h = new HeadElement();
 h.children.add(e);
 document.head.children.add(h);
```

Comment: Do you really need the `HeadElement`? I had expected that you can do `document.head.append(new LinkElement()..rel = 'import'..href='my-tag.html');`. Does this also work when built to JavaScript?

Comment: @JoaoBiriba I'll try but I can already tell you this fact: even without (re-)adding the head element (which is already present in the document) by inspecting the dom with chrome I notice that the link element is actually added, and the exception is fired only when I try to add the component to the dom and not when adding the link tag. On the other side if I add the link tag "manually" it works.

Comment: Built in js give same result, however you solution is cleaner, don't sure if he really need HeadElement.

Comment: Another "intersting" fact is that, by inspecting the DOM I can see the "shadowDom" inside the link after it is added. This behaviour is different from when adding the link "at compile time". In this latter case infact you can see that the link tag are somewhat "eaten" by the Polymer engine and do not appear in the head anymore.